# read ENV?"Type: " results in `ENV?Type: ': not a valid identifier error

Tags: bash, syntax

I ran into the line `read ENV?"Type: "` in a script, and upon execution, I think I'm getting an error because Bash doesn't recognize the syntax. I didn't create the script, so this format of receiving input is unfamiliar to me. Was it meant to be used with a different shell other than Bash? If so, I'm not sure why the header is #!/bin/sh

Example usage in script:

```
echo "What type of environment is this? (Enter 1-4)"
read ENV?"Type: "
```

I'm assuming the expected result is `Type: <choice>` with "choice" being a number 1-4.

Comment: In `zsh`, that `read` command is equivalent to `bash`'s `read -p "Type: " ENV`, although you may need to escape the question mark to prevent filename generation.

Comment: ksh also uses that syntax.

Comment: Sorry to comment on this so late, but I believe the script was made for ksh. My work also has a lot of other scripts that use #!/bin/ksh